# size of \boxplus vs. \boxminus

Tags: align, amsmath, size, stmaryrd

I redefined the `\boxplus` and `\boxminus` commands.  But for some reasons, the + sign inside the `\boxplus` is too large while the - sign in the `\boxminus` has he correct size.  How should I modify the macros to have the two symbols of the right size?

Note that I am also using `\boxdot` in my document and the box for `\boxdot` is smaller than that of `\boxplus`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,stmaryrd}


\makeatletter 
\newcommand*{\b@xplus}[1][+]{\ooalign{%
    $\m@th\vcenter{\hbox{$\m@th#1$}}$\cr%
    \hidewidth$\m@th\boxempty$\hidewidth\cr}} 
\renewcommand*{\boxplus}{\mathbin{\b@xplus}} 
\renewcommand*{\boxminus}{\mathbin{\b@xplus[-]}} 
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$a \boxplus b$  % incorrect size

$a \boxminus b$ % correct size

\end{document}
```

Comment: Off topic: why don't you just use `\scalebox` on normal `\boxplus` and `\boxminus`?

Comment: What's the reason for the redefinition? As far as I can see, `stmaryrd`'s `\boxplus` has the same dimensions as `+`.

Comment: I am also using `\boxdot` in my document and the box for `\boxdot` is smaller than that of `\boxplus`. (The box used for `\boxdot` appears to be the same as `\boxempty`.)

Comment: @user94293 -- you should add that reason to the question.

Comment: `amssymb` has all three, `\boxplus`, `\boxminus`, and `\boxdot`, and all three should be the same size, so no scaling should be necessary.

Comment: What I don't like in `ams` symbol `\boxplus` is that it is not vertically centered (i.e., as a regular + is); it seems to aligned on the baseline. The symbols defined is `stmaryrd` are vertically centered.

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but `\let\originalboxplus\boxplus 
\renewcommand*\boxplus{\mathbin{\mathop\originalboxplus}}` would give you a vertically centred `\boxplus`.

Comment: @Circumscribe: Yes but this answers the problem :)  Why does mathop center material in this case?

Comment: @user94293: If `\mathop` is applied to a single character (and only then!), it will centre this character on the math axis (because the large math operators generally are, I guess). This can be quite useful :).

Comment: You run into two bugs. First bug is in CM fonts, where the minus shape from cmsy10 is smaller than plus shape from cmr10. Second bug is in AMS fonts, where the symbols boxplus, boxminus from msam10 are not centered to math axis. If you use another math fonts (for example Unicode Latin Modern Math) then both bugs are corrected.

Comment: @Circumscribe You might want to add an answer.

Comment: @egreg: I started typing, but I'm too slow/distracted :). The first half of your answer addresses the actual question being asked, so this is much better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the plus sign overshoots the minus sign, while both have the same width, as far as TeX is concerned. The `\boxempty` symbol of `stmaryrd` has the same width as both.

You can work around the issue by using a slightly smaller plus, raised by a small amount so it still sits well with respect to the formula axis.

[image]

The gray line in the picture shows the formula axis (`xcolor` is used just for this). The final line shows the overshooting.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,stmaryrd}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\reducedplus}{\mathpalette\reduced@plus\relax}
\newcommand{\reduced@plus}[2]{%
  \sbox6{$\m@th#1+$}%
  \sbox8{\scalebox{0.875}{\copy6}}%
  \dimen@=\dimexpr(\wd6-\wd8)/3\relax
  \raisebox{\dimen@}{\box8}%
}
\newcommand{\boxoperation}[2][\mathbin]{%
  #1{\mathpalette\box@operation{#2}}%
}
\newcommand{\box@operation}[2]{%
  \ooalign{$\m@th#1\boxempty$\cr\hidewidth$\m@th#1#2$\hidewidth\cr}%
}
\newcommand{\boxplus}{\boxoperation{\reducedplus}}
\newcommand{\boxminus}{\boxoperation{-}}

\begin{document}

\indent\rlap{\color{black!10}$\frac{\hspace{1cm}}{}$}%
$a\boxplus b\boxminus c$

\indent\rlap{\color{black!10}$\scriptstyle\frac{\hspace{1cm}}{}$}%
$\scriptstyle a\boxplus b\boxminus c$

\indent\rlap{\color{black!10}$\scriptscriptstyle\frac{\hspace{1cm}}{}$}%
$\scriptscriptstyle a\boxplus b\boxminus c$

\mbox{}%
{\ooalign{\textcolor{red}{$+$}\cr$-$\cr}}
{\ooalign{\textcolor{red}{$-$}\cr$+$\cr}}
{\ooalign{$+$\cr\textcolor{red}{$-$}\cr}}

\end{document}
```

On the other hand, you could more simply use the symbols provided by `amssymb`, which is essentially the same, but simpler, than wipet's answer.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\let\amssymbboxplus\boxplus
\let\amssymbboxminus\boxminus

\renewcommand{\boxplus}{\mathbin{\mathop\amssymbboxplus}}
\renewcommand{\boxminus}{\mathbin{\mathop\amssymbboxminus}}

\begin{document}

$a+b-c$

$a\boxplus b\boxminus c$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

As I said in my comment, you have fallen into two bugs caused by someone else. First bug is in CM fonts, where the minus shape from cmsy10 is smaller than plus shape from cmr10. Second bug is in AMS fonts, where the symbols boxplus, boxminus from msam10 are not centered to math axis. If you use another math fonts (for example Unicode Latin Modern Math) then both bugs are corrected.

If you insist to use these fonts then you can do following:

```
\mathchardef\xboxplus=\numexpr \boxplus-"2000\relax
\def\boxplus{\mathbin{\mathop{\xboxplus}}}
\mathchardef\xboxminus=\numexpr \boxminus-"2000\relax
\def\boxminus{\mathbin{\mathop{\xboxminus}}}

test: $a + b \boxplus c \boxminus d$
```

I subtract "2000 from mathcode of `\boxplus` and `\boxminus` in order to get math Ord charcter (they are declared as math Bin). I need to do this conversion in order to use these characters in the context `\mathop{Ord}` which does centering to math axis (appendix G od TeXbook, paragraph 13). Finally, I re-define `\boxplus` and `\boxminus` as math Bin object.

The subtraction is necessary as shown from the following code and from the picture with the result.

```
\mathchardef\xboxplus=\numexpr \boxplus-"2000\relax
\def\boxplusEgreg{\mathbin{\mathop{\boxplus}}}
\def\boxplusWipet{\mathbin{\mathop{\xboxplus}}}

$a + b \boxplusWipet c \boxplusEgreg d$
```

[image: boxplus]

Comment: The subtraction is not necessary.

Comment: @egreg Substraction is necessery as shown in my actual version of the answer. Or, I didn't understand something.

Comment: Thank you @wipet!  Or equivalently, \renewcommand*{\boxplus}{\mathbin{\mathop{\mathchar"0401}}}

Comment: @wipet Your error is in the braces: it should be `\mathbin{\mathop\xboxplus}}`, which doesn't create a subformula. See the last part of my answer.

Comment: Or equivalently, \renewcommand*{\boxplus}{\mathbin{\mathop\mathchar"2401}}

Comment: @user94293 Or equivalently `\def\boxplus{\mathbin{\mathchar"1401}}` if you know the number of math family (4) and the slot number 01.